# How to test if var is not either of two strings?

Tags: python, if-statement

I've stumbled upon a problem I can't explain.

```
chosen = input()
if chosen == "1" or chosen == "2":
  print("Okay")
else:
  print("Please choose between 1 or 2.")
```

If written like that it executes as intended, but the flow felt weird, so I want to continue with else, so I changed the statement to !=

```
chosen = input()
if chosen != "1" or chosen != "2":
  print("Please choose between 1 or 2.")
else:
  print("Okay")
```

That way (to me) it feels natural to continue the code, but now no input returns "Okay".

Comment: You could have also wrapped your original expression in a *not*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you'd use `in` for this, which reads much cleaner

```
while True:
    chosen = input()
    if chosen in ["1", "2"]:
      print("Okay")
      break
    else:
      print("Please choose between 1 or 2.")
```

Comment: For a newbie, it's worth adding that you can negate it with `not in`

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and showing me your method. (Fluff again, sorry)
Using the while loop solved a problem I still didn't encounter at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the and keyword instead of or,

by using or this makes it so that if you answer 1 then it will not print "Okay" due to the fact that it is not 2 which makes the function true, and vice versa for the input equaling 2.

This should work:

```
chosen = input()
if chosen != "1" and chosen != "2":
  print("Please choose between 1 or 2.")
else:
  print("Okay")
```

Note you may benefit from changing the numbers into integers by doing this:

```
chosen = int(input())
if chosen != 1 and chosen != 2:
  print("Please choose between 1 or 2.")
else:
  print("Okay")
```

The int function makes your input into a number, however it will give an error if the user doesn't put in a number.